# keyboard-setup.service is slow at boot. Do I need it?

Tags: systemd, keyboard

My PC is running Debian Buster, and it's boot time seems to be slowed down by `keyboard-setup.service`. I understand that this is involved in setting up the keyboard for use at the console. The output of `systemd-analyze blame` is as below. I've checked it a number of times and it's always been similar.

```
 5.549s keyboard-setup.service
 5.063s dev-sda2.device
 4.140s udisks2.service
 3.565s accounts-daemon.service
 3.487s console-kit-log-system-start.service
```

This makes me wonder why I need to spend 5.5 seconds setting up my keyboard every time I boot. Is keyboard-setup supposed to be this slow?

If yes, then why? What's it doing? And is it safe to just disable it?

If no, then what's going wrong and how should I go about fixing it?

**Edit**: `systemd-analyse critical-chain`

```
graphical.target @17.385s
└─gdm.service @15.588s +1.797s
  └─rc-local.service @15.476s +110ms
    └─network.target @15.475s
      └─networking.service @14.971s +502ms
        └─apparmor.service @8.262s +3.147s
          └─local-fs.target @8.256s
            └─boot-efi.mount @8.000s +255ms
              └─local-fs-pre.target @7.971s
                └─keyboard-setup.service @2.421s +5.549s
                  └─systemd-journald.socket @2.420s
                    └─system.slice @2.417s
                      └─-.slice @2.186s
```

Comment: The service is taking a long time to timeout. Try to:

edit /lib/systemd/system/keyboard-setup.service,

and adding the line:

TimeoutStartSec=10sec

after the last line of [Service] bit.

Comment: You would have a better question for [edit]ing the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` into it.

Comment: @vfbsilva Unlike https://askubuntu.com/q/919428/309061, the service is taking 5 seconds to start, not 20. Adding `TimeoutStartSec=10sec` doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

By running `systemctl cat keyboard-setup.service` you can see its definition:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/keyboard-setup.service
[Unit]
Description=Set the console keyboard layout
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=local-fs-pre.target
Wants=local-fs-pre.target
ConditionPathExists=/bin/setupcon

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/lib/console-setup/keyboard-setup.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

So it runs `/lib/console-setup/keyboard-setup.sh`, but only if `/bin/setupcon` exists.

`/lib/console-setup/keyboard-setup.sh` is also pretty simple:

```
#!/bin/sh

if \
    [ -x /etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh ] \
        && /etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh
then
    :
else
    if [ -f /etc/default/locale ]; then
        # In order to permit auto-detection of the charmap when
        # console-setup-mini operates without configuration file.
        . /etc/default/locale
        export LANG
    fi
    setupcon -k
fi
```

Meaning:

- if `/etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh` exists and runs without errors, this script does nothing beyond running that script.
- otherwise, `setupcon -k` is executed, but if `/etc/default/locale` exists, it is read and the LANG variable is exported first.

At least on my system, `/etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh` does exist and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f /run/console-setup/keymap_loaded ]; then
    rm /run/console-setup/keymap_loaded
    exit 0
fi
kbd_mode '-u' < '/dev/tty1' 
kbd_mode '-u' < '/dev/tty2' 
kbd_mode '-u' < '/dev/tty3' 
kbd_mode '-u' < '/dev/tty4' 
kbd_mode '-u' < '/dev/tty5' 
kbd_mode '-u' < '/dev/tty6' 
loadkeys '/etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz' > '/dev/null'
```

Meaning:

- if the marker file `/run/console-setup/keymap_loaded` exists (indicating that the console keymap was already loaded in early-boot initramfs), the file is cleaned up and the script does nothing else, exiting without an error.
- otherwise, the first 6 virtual consoles are initialized in UTF-8 Unicode mode, and a keymap file is loaded.

Based on this, you might try:

- examining your `/etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh` and `/etc/default/locale` to see if they're corrupted or contain something more time-consuming than usual
- if `/etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh` does not exist, you might try creating one similar to my example above (it might be created by some GUI keyboard setup tool, and the commands used might be faster than `setupcon -k`)
- if `/etc/console-setup/cached_setup_keyboard.sh` exists, you could try temporarily making it non-executable, booting the system and testing the keyboard to see if the layout is usable and if the execution path through `setupcon -k` is any faster than the current path
- setting `KEYMAP=y` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and running `update-initramfs -u` and seeing if it makes things any faster by loading the keymap in initramfs and causing the `keyboard-setup.service` to be essentially bypassed

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion is to put a timeout limitation for the service to control the time it consumes at start up. 
You may do this with two methods:

```
SERVICETOFIX="keyboard-setup.service"
sudo mkdir -p "/etc/systemd/system/$SERVICETOFIX.d"
sudo echo -e "[Service]\nTimeoutStartSec=10" | tee "/etc/systemd/system/$SERVICETOFIX.d/reduce-timeout.conf"
```

Method 2: I personally prefer this method:
First run `sudo systemctl edit keyboard-setup.service`, and then in the editor add the below and then save and exit the editor.

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=10
```

Comment: Hi AndyBaba! Thanks for the advice, but it was made clear in the comments on the question why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi GKFX:) I guess in that regard you are right, however this is still a helpful tip to use for similar cases caused by other services. I do apologize if my answer if its not helpful though.